# Update image src on the fly with VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'm a new **VueJS** user, currently struggling with updating image src on the fly. This is what I've got:

*Template:*

```
<div v-for="place in places">
    <img 
        v-bind:src="isPlacePrivate(place.data.place_is_private)" 
        v-on:click="setPlaceAsPrivate(place.data.place_is_private, place.data.place_id)"
    >
</div>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                places: null,
            }
        },

        mounted () {
            this.username = this.$route.params.username;

            axios.get('/api/' + this.username + '/places')
                .then(response => {
                    this.places = response.data.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // show error
                });
        },

        methods: {
            isPlacePrivate: function (value) {
                // If Place is private
                if (value == 1) {
                    var src = '/icons/padlock-color.png'
                } else {
                    var src = '/icons/padlock.png'
                }

                return src;
            },

            setPlaceAsPrivate: function (value, placeId) {
                let data = {
                    isPrivate: value
                };

                axios.put('/api/' + this.username + '/places/' + placeId + '/edit', data)
                    .then(response => {
                        let newValue = response.data.data.private;

                        this.isPlacePrivate(newValue);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        // show error
                    });
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

On a page load -> if a particular place is private it will show colored padlock icon or uncolored padlock if a place is public!

A user will be able to press on the padlock icon and change the value from public->private or private->public.

Everything is working fine but the padlock image is not updating on the fly when a user is clicking on it, I need to refresh a page to see changes! How to make it work?

Comment: Is is practical to copy the state of all of the places into your component's state (`data`) when the component mounts? On update you can then update the state and make your API call. Additionally you could periodically poll the API to get the latest results in case other clients are making changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a computed property so that it is reactive

Also according to your updates you are looping through an array of places so when you get your response from your axios call instead of just updating the icon I would try replacing the object in the array so I created the method called `updatePlace()` and I pass in the response object.

And change your places in the v-for to a computed property as well so that it is also reactive

Template:

```
<div v-for="place in placesArray" :key="index" v-if="places">
  <img 
    v-bind:src="imgSrc" 
    v-on:click="setPlaceAsPrivate(place.data.place_is_private, place.data.place_id)"
    v-if="imgSrc"
>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
 data() {
    return {
       src: '',
       places: null 
    }     
  },
  computed: {
     imgSrc() {
        return this.src
     },
     placesArray() {
       return this.places
     }
  },
Methods: {
    isPlacePrivate: function (value) {
    // If Place is private
    if (value == 1) {
        this.src = '/icons/padlock-color.png'
    } else {
        this.src = '/icons/padlock.png'
    }
},
setPlaceAsPrivate: function (value, placeId) {
    let data = {
        isPrivate: value
    };
    axios.put('/api/' + this.username + '/places/' + placeId + '/edit', data)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            let newValue = response.data.data;
            this.updatePlace(newValue);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
  updatePlace(newPlace) {
    const index = this.places.findIndex(place => place.id === newPlace.id)
    this.places.splice(index, 1, place)
  },
  created() {
     this.username = this.$route.params.username;

        axios.get('/api/' + this.username + '/places')
            .then(response => {
                this.places = response.data.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // show error
        });
   }
}
</script>
```

Also make sure to move your `mounted` method to a `created()` method so that it is called before anything else is trying to render.

Comment: Thank you for you reply but I don't it will work in my case, have a look at my updated post. You see on the page load, different padlock icons should be shown depending on privacy set by a user, but with your solution it will always be empty!

Comment: see my update. I added a lot and it may be confusing but you should move your mounted section to a `created()` method along with replacing the object in your array to the updated place.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is that you are calling the function and printing its return on the `<img v-bind:src>`, the `isPlacePrivate` function returns a value, so when you use this function within the `setPlaceAsPrivate` it returns the value only in scope of `setPlaceAsPrivate`.
The `isPlacePrivate` function does not modify any `data` value of the component, so the image always remains the same. You just need to set a `data` and manipulate its value in the `isPlacePrivate` function.

Template

```
  <img 
        v-bind:src="bindSrc" 
        v-on:click="setPlaceAsPrivate(place.data.place_is_private, place.data.place_id)"
    >
```

Script

```
<script>
 export default {
     data() {
        return {
           bindSrc: '/icons/padlock-color.png',  // default img src value
           ... // your other values
        }     
    },
    Methods: {
        isPlacePrivate: function (value) {
        // If Place is private
        if (value == 1) {
            this.bindSrc = '/icons/padlock-color.png'
        } else {
            this.bindSrc = '/icons/padlock.png'
        }
    },
    setPlaceAsPrivate: function (value, placeId) {
        let data = {
            isPrivate: value
        };
        axios.put('/api/' + this.username + '/places/' + placeId + '/edit', data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                let newValue = response.data.data.private;
                this.isPlacePrivate(newValue);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply but I don't it will work in my case, have a look at my updated post. You see on the page load, different padlock icons should be shown depending on privacy set by a user, but with your solution it will always be the same value until user changes it!